# Dynamic filename with current date in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

How can I append current date to the end of filename when i export reports from JasperReports Server? 
For example if filename is orders, then i need to get the filename as orders_13-06-2018.xls if i export it  today and orders_12-06-2018.xls if i export it tomorrow and so on.

I have tried using scheduler in JRS but it shows only date for a particular time.

This solutions are not working:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/914536/netsfjasperreportsexportxlssheetname-usable

https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/515739/jasper-report-download-file-name

Comment: How do you export these files? Are you using REST?

Comment: I am exporting it in csv or excel format directly from jasper reports server.

Comment: Have you tried "timestamp pattern" see https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-user-guide/setting-output-options